# Asp Core - Tree Structure - mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm creating a tree structure where are Nodes and Leaves. Each Node has SubNodes and SubLeaves.

Here are the structure of entities:

Node:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace TreeWithReact.Entities
{
    public class Node
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int NodeId { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ParentNodeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ParentNodeId")]
        public Node ParentNode { get; set; }
        public List<Node> SubNodes { get; set; }
        public List<Leaf> SubLeaves { get; set; }
        public Node()
        {
            SubNodes = new List<Node>();
            SubLeaves = new List<Leaf>();
        }
    }
}
```

Leaf:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TreeWithReact.Entities
{
    public class Leaf
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int LeafId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ParentNodeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ParentNodeId")]
        public Node ParentNode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and relations:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
                .HasMany(cat => cat.SubNodes)
                .WithOne(cat => cat.ParentNode);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
                .HasMany(cat => cat.SubLeaves)
                .WithOne(cat => cat.ParentNode);
        }
```

Here is the method which is responsible for get whole tree:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<NodeModel>> GetTreeAsync()
        {
            var nodes = await _context.Nodes.ToListAsync();

            return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<NodeModel>>(nodes);
        }
```

Nodes are mapped to NodeModel:

```
    public class NodeModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<NodeModel> SubNodes { get; set; }
        public List<LeafModel> SubLeaves { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the AutoMapper configuration:

```
            CreateMap<Node, NodeModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SubLeaves, opt => opt.MapFrom<IEnumerable<Leaf>>(src => src.SubLeaves));
```

But in result, I receive an empty array of SubLeaves, SubNodes appear properly. I don't know maybe something in onModelCreating is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I forgot to add Include to get list of Nodes method. And the mapper ForMember method is not necessary.

```
var nodes = await _context.Nodes.Include(x => x.SubLeaves).ToListAsync();
```